# Set menu active based on current page or URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code for the main menu:

```html
<ul class="menu-nav">
      <li id="current" class="active item53"><a href="Default.aspx"><span>
            Home</span></a></li>
      <li class="item54"><a href="onlineshop.aspx"><span>
            Shop</span></a></li>
      <li class="item28"><a href="newproducts.aspx"><span>
            New</span></a></li>
      <li class="item29"><a href="clientinfo.aspx"><span>
            Info</span></a></li>
      <li class="item18"><a href="aboutus.aspx"><span>
            About Us</span></a></li>
      <li class="item30"><a href="contactus.aspx"><span>
            Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Now the active menu is always item53, the "Home" menu.

I need a code snippet that changes the menu button, based on the current page.

For example: if I'm on the contactus.aspx page, change class value to : "active item30"

Comment: i searched/tested a few solutions, but some solutions that i find don't fit my needs. Sorry for duplicate question and Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get page from `location.href` and using that update corresponding class:

```
let pageName = location.pathname.split("/").find(function(element) {
    if (element.indexOf(".aspx") > 0)
       return element;
});
if (typeof pathName != 'undefined') {
    $(".menu-nav li").removeClass("active");
    $("[href='"+pathName+"']").parent().addClass("active");
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, i rewrite a bit your code to fit my needs. Here is my code: `<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 var pathName = String(location.pathname=="/" ? "Default.aspx" :location.pathname.split("/")[1]);

 if (typeof pathName != 'undefined') {
  var className = $("[href='"+pathName+"']").parent();
  $(".menu-nav li").removeClass("active");
  $("[href='"+pathName+"']").parent().addClass("active "+className);
 }
});
</script>`

Comment: @SteveMiller glad the code helped